# How to set the video (in slider) to auto start only it appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, slider

I am working on a slider, one of the slides is a video, how to not to let it plays while other slides are sliding and to autoplay right at the moment it appears. The video last 30 sec.

Comment: Without showing any code noone will be able to help you - please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a nice way for auto playing the video when it appears using only the `autoplay` html attribute on the element. But you should be able to get the desired effect with some simple javascript.

If you are using an HTML5 video element remove the `autoplay` attribute to prevent it from starting to play when it is not visible. On slide change, check whether the currently visible element is your video and if so call `.play()` on the video element to start it. Once it is not visible anymore (on the next slide change) call `.pause()` on the element to stop execution.

If you want to start the video from the beginning next time it is visible call `.load()` once it is not visible anymore to reload the video and start it from the beginning next time. Otherwise it will continue playing where it left off last time it was visible.

Check this for a reference of methods available on the video element:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement